# Find index which has minimum value in sublist C#

Tags: c#, indexof

I want to find index in which that index has minimum value for a sublist.
I have a class name Subproblem like this:

```
public class Subproblem
{
    public double[,] x { get; set; }
    public double ReducedCost { get; set; }
}
```

then I want to find the index of subproblem which has the minimum value of reduced cost.

```
var sub = new List<Subproblem>();
Subproblem s = new Subproblem();
s.x = new double[DC1, DC1];
for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m)
{
  s.ReducedCost = model.ObjVal;
  for (int i = 0; i < DC1; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < DC1; ++j)
    {
     s.x[i, j] = x[i, j].X;
    }
  }
  sub.Add(s);
}
double minRC = sub.Min(a => a.ReducedCost);
int minRCIndex = sub.IndexOf(minRC);
```

The last line is still error but i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify what your error is.

Comment: @Tom int minRCIndex = sub.IndexOf(minRC); this syntax is still error (have red underline)

Comment: Can you add your sample in [dotnetfidlde](http://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Try `sub.IndexOf(s=> s.ReducedCost == minRC);`

Comment: Its because you try to look for a double in a list of "subproblems". With indexOf you're expected to give a Subproblem in this case.

Comment: @aloisdg here is my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/3EOWDn

Comment: @Developer I have tried yours but it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because `minRC` has type `double` but in your case `IndexOf()` expects parameter type `Subproblem`.

You should use `FindIndex()`:

```
int minRCIndex = sub.FindIndex((i) => i.ReducedCost == minRC);
```

Also, you can change these two lines:

```
double minRC = sub.Min(a => a.ReducedCost);
int minRCIndex = sub.IndexOf(minRC);
```

to only one:

```
 int minRCIndex = sub.FindIndex(i => i.ReducedCost == sub.Min(a => a.ReducedCost));
```